# Django from Python VS SQL for making database

Tags: sql, django

Basically do you guys know which one would it be better to use between Django and SQL for database?

And in terms of effectivity which one would be better?

Answer (score 3):

Django and SQL are not replacements for one another, Django is a web framework as a whole, designed to develop web applications, and SQL is a language to query databases.

But if you have a task you can perform using either one of these, you can get a better performance using raw SQL than Django and its ORM, depending on your task. As Django is a framework suitable for many different problems, SQL queries issued by it might not be optimal for certain needs. So you can write more optimal queries in SQL for your specific problems.